# Facebook PHP SDK Download all photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Good Afternoon,

Is there an api method/loop which will allow me to access all of a users photos? Keep in mind I do not want tags or albums, I want all pictures.  Appreciate the help.

I have tried api photos method yet it does not do what I wish.

Comment: You'll have to go through each album.

Comment: but what if photos are not in album?

Comment: All photos are in albums

Comment: @MrAzulay Is correct. Profile photos will be in the Profile Photos album. Photos posted directly to the wall will be in Wall Photos, and photos uploaded from mobile will be in Mobile Uploads (or the translated equivalent of each depending on the user's language).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got the user_photos permission and make a request with graphpath me/photos. You are gonna get all photos he uploaded and is tagged in. Although these are easily removed by just checking who uploaded the image (this is included in the response JSON).